# Dynamically Add a Row to a Gridview at Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Is it possible to add a row to a gridview at runtime? I need to add a default row(sometimes) and then add an adhoc row after the bound row based on a value in the bound row.

```
gridView.DataSource = source;
/// Create a new Default Row here
gridview.DataBind();
```

AND

```
OnDataBound(object sender, DataGridEventArgs e)
//evaluate each row and if certain criteria add a new row.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to determine if you need to add additional rows before databinding.

Answer (score 4):

[This](http://blog.falafel.com/2007/04/12/DynamicallyAddRowsToAGridView.aspx) might solve your problem.